# How can I use matplotlib ticklabel_format to not use scientific notation on y axis labels

Tags: matplotlib

I'm creating a plot (in a colab worksheet) and want the y tick labels to not use scientific notation. The ticklabel_format doesn't make any difference to the final graph. The y axis labels are still shown as 10^3 instead of 1000. How do I format the y tick labels to not use scientific notation? 
Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.plot(Cd_rank,Cd_raw,linewidth=4)
plt.plot(Cd_rank,Cd_sed,linewidth=4)
plt.plot(Cd_rank,Cd_filter,linewidth=4)
plt.plot([0,1],[0.3,0.3],linewidth=4)
plt.plot([0,1],[5,5],linewidth=4)
plt.ylabel('Turbidez (UTN)')
plt.xlabel('Datos ordenados')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(['Agua cruda','Decantada','Filtrada','Norma EPA','Norma ENACAL'])
```

Comment: `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter( matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())`

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ticker'. I replaced matplotlib with plt.

Comment: Well, you need `matplotlib.ticker` as `plt.ticker`doesn't exist.  Add `import matplotlib` (and also keep `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).

Comment: I've added the matplotlib import. Thanks!
I'm assuming I need to add something like ```plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter( matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(style='plain', axis='y'))``` because ```plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter( matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())``` doesn't seem to do anything. I suspect I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ScalarFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) shows the tick labels in a default format. Note that depending on your concrete situation, matplotlib still might be using scientific notation:

- When the numbers are too high (default this is about 4 digits). `set_powerlimits((n, m))` can be used to change the limits.
- In case the numbers are very close together, matplotlib describes the range using an offset. That offset is placed at the top of the axis. This can be suppressed with the  `useOffset=None` parameter of the formatter.
- In some cases with a logarithmic scale, there are very few major ticks. Then also some (but not all) minor ticks get a label. Also for these, the formatter could be changed. A problem can be that a simple `ScalarFormatter` will set too many labels. Either suppress all these minor labels using a `NullFormatter` or you'll need a very custom formatter that returns empty strings for the minor tick labels that need to be suppressed.

A simple example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

N = 50
Cd_rank = np.linspace(0, 100, N)
Cd_raw = np.random.normal(1, 20, N).cumsum() + 100

plt.plot(Cd_rank, Cd_raw, linewidth=4)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0.3, 0.3], linewidth=4)
plt.plot([0, 1], [5, 5], linewidth=4)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
plt.show()
```

And here is a more complicated example, with both minor (green) and major (red) ticks.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

N = 50
Cd_rank = np.linspace(0, 100, N)
Cd_raw = np.random.normal(10, 5, N).cumsum() + 80

plt.plot(Cd_rank, Cd_raw, linewidth=4)
plt.yscale('log')
mticker = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
mticker.set_powerlimits((-6, 6))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mticker)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', colors='crimson')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', colors='seagreen')
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

PS: When the ticks involve both powers of 10 larger than 1 and smaller than 1 (so, e.g. `100, 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01`) the ScalarFormatter doesn't display the numbers smaller than 1 well (it displays `0.1` and `0.01` as `0`). In that case, the [`StrMethodFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter) can be used instead:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x}"))
```

Comment: Excellent! How can I make matplotlib show the correct number of digits for numbers less than 1? It currently displays 0 instead of 0.1? Or should I post this as a different question?

See this code

`N = 50`
`Cd_rank = np.linspace(0, 1, N)`
`Cd_raw = np.logspace(-2,3,N)`
`np.random.normal()`
`plt.plot(Cd_rank, Cd_raw, linewidth=4)`
`plt.plot([0, 1], [0.3, 0.3], linewidth=4)`
`plt.plot([0, 1], [5, 5], linewidth=4)`
`plt.yscale('log')`
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())`
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())`
`plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that turns off scientific notation and handles numbers that are smaller than 1 correctly. Thanks to @Johanc for this code.

````
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

N = 50
x = np.linspace(0,1,N)
y = np.logspace(-3, 2, N)

plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=4)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(bottom=0.001,top=100)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x}"))
plt.show()```
````